# how i can create reCAPTCHA for my own widget

Tags: javascript, reactjs, widget, recaptcha

Can you please tell me if it is possible to embed the google recaptcha into my own widget? If so, how?

Otherwise, to create a recaptcha, a domain is required, but it will be constantly different since it will be embedded on sites. So the question arose, is it possible to do this at all?

Is it possible to enter the domain on which the widget itself is located, or will it not work like this?

I am currently using react-recaptcha-v3 but maybe there is a better option

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to look into this library: https://github.com/appleboy/react-recaptcha

In order to use it, you'll need to follow their instructions for signing up for an API key, but this should provide you what you need!

Comment: I used the react-recaptcha-v3 package, which is essentially the same as what you dropped, but the problem is the same. When registering a recaptcha, in order to get an api key, you need to enter a domain, but which domain should I enter if I need to embed the recaptcha in my own widget. Is this even possible, if so, how?